# adding and remove classes on click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am working on a click event, which intially is pretty standard.

on.click: Remove the active class from all list items, then add active to the clicked list item.

ie

```
var li = $('.child-item');
li.click(function(){
  li.removeClass('active');
  li.addClass('active');
});
```

Works as expected. However, I also need a condition that if the active class is clicked again, it will remove the active class from the clicked item.

I tried this:

```
$('.child-item').toggle(function(e){
    
   $('.child-item').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');

}, function() {
   $('.child-item').removeClass('active');
   $(this).removeClass('active');           
});
```

but often the toggle is in the off state, so it requires a double click to get the toggle back on track. This seems like it would be a pretty straightforward solution, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

[Added a jsFiddle here with another option](https://jsfiddle.net/81ex7dmm/1/). This is fine for when the same element is clicked, but it doesn't clear all active classes on each click.

## Update

I got it working but TrueBlueAussie's answer is shorter and better. Here is my working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/v7b8cbj5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second click handler will only attach to matching "active" items when the event was registered.

Replace it all with just this:

```
$('.child-item').click(function(e){
   $('.child-item.active').not(this).removeClass('active');    
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

You can use `not()` to exclude the current item from selected list of things to make inactive, then just toggle the selected one.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/81ex7dmm/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var li = $('.child-item');
li.click(function(){
  li.removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: This variation does not allow you to turn off active on the current item. Use `toggleClass` instead for that one.

Answer (score 0):

> **[.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)** (Event) -  is deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9

---

Use `add()` with `toggleClass()` on `.active` `<li>`

```
$('.child-item').click(function(e){
    $('li.child-item.active').add(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81ex7dmm/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try it also :

```
$('.child-item').click(function(e){
   $('.child-item.active').removeClass('active');    
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/81ex7dmm/4/)